# How to get checkin data from facebook account and friends/others data

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using facebook-ios-sdk-3.11.1 and Xcode 5 and i need to support ios 5,6,7

[Old Facebook Doc for checkin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/)

[New Facebook Doc for checkin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/checkins/)

From this info i have found following code needs to be implemented

```
     [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/checkins"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          NSLog(@"result %@",result);

                      }];
```

**Outuput:**

```
result {
data =     (
);
```

}

I am getting no results even though i have checkin to one place from my facebook account

And how can we get data of friends checkin of user's friends as well